# Make a UIWebview display dektop not mobile page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, http-headers, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm making a simple `UIWebView` iOS app. In it, the website I want to display is displaying as the mobile version, when I want it to display as the full version.

I have this code under `viewDidLoad:`

```
NSString *fullURL = @"www.facebook.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
// [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```

The commented out code I have found makes the website display as the mobile version. Does anyone know how I could change commented line to be the desktop version? When the commented line stays commented, it still runs as the mobile version.

Thanks that would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

set a **desktop** user agent for HTTP requests:  e.g. '@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2";'

BUT that doesnt work for a webview because the webview doesn't use the agent set for the request. Instead, it uses the agent from NSUserDefaults.

so:

```
NSString *secretagent = @"%%MyUserAgent%%"; //the one you chose
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:secretAgent, @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

to get this to take effect, do it before you load the UIWebview!

Comment: the user agent provided was taken from OSX 10.6.8, safari 5. it is old. but google should help you find better strings

Comment: No that's ok. I have no idea what they are nor what they do so I'll do a bit of research into them now! Thank you!

Comment: Nah it's still not working. I've tried many different one's from that site (Thanks @JacobOscarson). Do you have any ideas why @Daij-Djan? My current code is:     NSString *userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36";
    
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://www.facebook.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [self.webView loadRequest: request];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247305/setting-ios-useragent-via-nsuserdefaults-works-half-the-time